# SQL Server Trigger Variable scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Could you please tell me what's wrong this this trigger (below is just a portion of the trigger).
When put variable on where parameter I don't get any result, instead, when I set is a default value I get correct result

Like this it doesn't work (I verified and `@Cont_local` is not null and data really exists inside the database):

Note:
info (information) is in a different table but on the same database.
the trigger is set to work on Cont (Contact) Table

```
select @Cont_local = ContID  from inserted
SET @Addr = (select Addr from Info I where I.ContID = @Cont_local)
```

But like this, it works

```
select @Cont_local = '454877'
SET @Addr = (select Addr from Info I where I.ContID = @Cont_local)
```

While `@Cont_local` is returning some values, the select statement cannot detect it.
Is this related to the scope of `@Cont_local` variable or something else?
Instead, when I try to put data manually, query return values and store it on `@Addr`

Here is Complete code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert__]
ON [dbo].[Cont]
AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN
DECLARE @Cont_local nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @firstnameme nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @Addr nvarchar(50);


select @Name = contName  from inserted
select @firstname = contfirstname  from inserted
select @Cont_local = ContID  from inserted

SET @Addr = (select Addr from Info I where I.ContID = @Cont_local)

INSERT INTO Final_Contact (Name, firstname, address) values
(@Name, @firstname ,@Addr)


END
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is rather vague.  What exactly is happening?

Comment: the last value is insert inside @Cont_local
But when I put inside where statement as a parameter, the select statement doesn't return anything

Comment: No one can debug fragments of code. And your trigger is fundamentally flawed, as already noted. Fix it before you (or someone else) discover that fact along with the false assumption that only one row will EVER be inserted (or updated or deleted - how are we supposed to know) at a time.

Comment: I've added full code as you told me

Comment: @BrentOzar talks on this [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Answer (score 0):

select @Cont_local = ContID  from inserted

This line of code works only when in the inserted-table is only one record

Comment: Yes it works because it is triggered after a new line is inserted and its value is unique
But when I put the value inside "where" statement, the select querry doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the original version of the question.

I don't see why your code would return an error.  However, it is malformed and an error waiting to happen.  Let me explain.

This code:

```
select @Cont_local = ContID from inserted
```

Assumes that `inserted` has one row.  Of course, the code runs when `inserted` has more than one row.  It just returns one value.

The `inserted` and `deleted` views in SQL Server triggers can refer to multiple rows.  In other words, triggers are *set-based* processing rather than row-by-row processing.  In a properly structured trigger, the references should always be in `FROM` clauses.

The following example is totally made up, but it illustrates how to update a column in another table using information from `inserted`:

```
update a
    set addr = c.addr
    where inserted i join
          info i
          on i.contid = a.contid join
          addresses a
          on a.addrid = i.addrid
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff.
I updated the body of my post and I will try to take not of your explanation

Comment: @NJR_92 . . . Your original question was answered twice.  I would suggest that you undo your changes to the question and ask a *new* question.